# How to put all replacements in one output in Python?

Tags: python, replace

I'm using the code

```
def callback():
  global text
  for k, v in mapping:
      print text.replace(k, v)
```

With the list

```
mapping = [ ('and', 'for'), ('you', 'me'), ('more', 'less'), ('always', 'never') ]
```

And the output comes out to

```
'for you more always'

'and me more always'

'and you less always'

'and you more never'
```

How do I make it so the output becomes

```
'for me less never'
```

Comment: What is the condition you're looking for? If you know the condition, what's wrong with using that? I'm not really sure what you're trying to achieve. What is `text`?

Comment: Give us your actual code, not just bits of it. As far as I can see you didn't even tell us the input.

Comment: beware of words in words: `for` => `band`, then `band` => `bfor` because it replaces `and`. Regex + word boundary is probably the best choice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def callback(text):
    for k, v in mapping:
        text = text.replace(k, v)
    return text

print callback(text)
```

You are printing for each iteration of the loop. Instead you want to do all the substitutions first, and then print. `text` is a string and thus immutable, which means `text.replace` won't change `text`; it returns a new string, which it's easiest to assign back to the variable `text`.

By the way, you should only use global variables when it is really necessary, and it's definitely not necessary here, you can just pass the variable to the function. And it's generally easier to have functions output by returning a value, rather than printing. This way you can do whatever you want with the output, including printing it, as I have done in the code.

Comment: that works, yes, but a little explanation would be welcome.

Comment: It's a bit hard to anticipate exactly which basic misconceptions the questioner was having (control flow? mutables?), but I've tried my best and added some comments.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply!

Answer (score 0):

I would use regular expressions with word boundaries (so it's robust to word in word replacement) and a replacement function to perform the replacement in one go:

```
import re

mapping = [ ('and', 'for'), ('you', 'me'), ('more', 'less'), ('always', 'never') ]

mapping_dict = dict(mapping)

text = 'and you more always'
search_re = re.compile("("+"|".join([r"\b{}\b".format(s) for s,_ in mapping])+")")

print(search_re.sub(lambda g : mapping_dict[g.group(1)],text))
```

The expression is made of the "keys" of the map or'ed together and using the `\b` boundary, here:

```
(\band\b|\byou\b|\bmore\b|\balways\b)
```

The regex magic happens when one of the word is found: the `lambda` function is called with the group containing the word, and since I had built a dictionary with the tuples list (which is trivial), just return the value associated to the word found.

```
for me less never
```

Answer (score 0):

First we can convert the list of tuple to dictionary so, it is faster to search for keys.

Then, we can split the sentence to words and search for keys on dictionary (*using get function*), if not by default return the same word.

Next we can use *generator* followed by *join* function rather than replacing (*strings are immutable*).

```
mapping = [ ('and', 'for'), ('you', 'me'), ('more', 'less'), ('always', 'never') ]
mapping_dict = dict(mapping)
print (" ".join(mapping_dict.get(word, word) for word in text.split()))
```